# Ubuntu login page: where to specify users list shown

Tags: ubuntu, login, gnome

Using Ubuntu 10.04.1 Desktop (Latest)

After the boot process, GDM shows the graphical login screen along with a list of users that can log in. Clicking a name will ask for its password.

I would like to modify that list and show only a restricted list of users.

(i.e., the other users may still be able to log in via the terminal access or 'su' - after Control-F4 for instance - but their login name should not appear on the Gnome login page).

Please let me know where to find that file(?).
I would like to perform the change from the terminal window (not the graphical environment), after a ssh for instance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In `/etc/gdm/custom.conf`, add the following stanza:

```
[greeter]
Exclude=nobody,wont_appear1,wont_appear2
```

If you want an inclusive list, I think the following will work (though it will also show users who recently logged in by entering their name manually):

```
[greeter]
IncludeAll=false
Include=will_appear1,will_appear2
```

Users with a UID <1000 won't appear unless explicitly included (I don't this this is configurable). Any user can still log in by explicitly typing their user name.

Reference: [gdm manual](http://library.gnome.org/admin/gdm/2.30/configuration.html.en)

If you want to forbid some users from logging in (as opposed to not showing their name and picture), add a filter to `/etc/pam.d/gdm`. Something like (untested; see `man pam_succeed_if` for details):

```
auth  required  pam_succeed_if.so user ingroup may_log_in_with_gdm
```

Comment: Note: Changes will only take affect after a reboot.

Comment: @Gili: You don't need to reboot, but you do need to restart Gdm. The next time you log out to the Gdm prompt, press `Ctrl+Alt+Backspace` to restart the X server and the login manager.

Comment: You can also restart GDM using `sudo service gdm restart`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to hide entire list open the terminal and enter the following comamnd :

```
sudo gconftool-2 --direct --config-source xml:readwrite:/etc/gconf/gconf.xml.mandatory --type Boolean --set /apps/gdm/simple-greeter/disable_user_list True
```

For remove only some user for the list you need to change UID to a number < 1000

The gdm login list lists any Ubuntu login user with a UID >=1000

This means as long as you get a login set to use a UID <1000 it will NOT show up in the gdm login list.

here's how:

```
System -> Administration -> Users and Groups
```

Edit the user by click on properties, go to advanced, then change the "User ID" to a different number. Try and make sure it's not already used by another person by looking at /etc/passwd